# How can I compare two hex strings in Bash?

Tags: bash, type-conversion

## **Problem:**

I fetch a few addresses from the Linux kernel symbol table using `cat`, `grep` , and `cut` in a Bash script. The end result is some string variables like `ADDR1` and `ADDR2` shown below.

```
ADDR1="ffffffffc1000000"
ADDR2="ffffffffc117f000"
```

In my script, I want to be able to compare these addresses (less than, greater than, equal to, etc.) like so:

```
if [ $ADDR1 -lt $ADDR2 ]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Since they are hex strings, I am having a hard time figuring out a good way to convert them to unsigned hex numbers that allows for comparison. This is what I need help with.

## **What I've Tried**

Since addresses are unsigned, I can't do tricks like I have seen in other posts, such as:

```
user@debian:~$ echo $((0x$ADDR1))
-1056964608
```

Additionally, other posts I have seen that deal with conversion talk about turning ASCII characters into hex or something similar where the output is a hex string, which isn't what I want as that can't be used for numeric comparison, and I already have a hex string :).

Comment: Peruse `man bc` and/or `man dc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[[`.

```
if [[ 0x$ADDR1 -lt 0x$ADDR2 ]]; then
  : do something
fi
```